# Get center of a UIView after CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

Suppose I had a small UIView as a child/subview of a larger UIView, and that child could be moved around via some CGAffineTransforms.  How might the the parent know what the true 'center' of that view is within its own coordinate system?  I have tried using the convertPoint routines with whatever is returned by child.center, but it isn't working... is 'center' completely bogus in this context or am I just using the wrong method?

Comment: I don't know how center behaves in the presence of CGAffineTransforms but you shouldn't have to use convertPoint since center is said to be "within the coordinate system of its superview".  (Or maybe I'm misinterpreting what you mean by "its own".)

Comment: Please give some examples of the code you're using and the values you're seeing. "Isn't working" is no help to anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After doing a bit of testing I noticed the following:

UIViews don't have an anchorPoint property, but they do have a center property. The center property is always calculated properly after applying transforms, except a translation transform, for which you have to do the following:

```
CGPoint realCenter = CGPointMake(myView.center.x + myView.frame.origin.x, ...);
```

As for `CALayer`s, they do have an anchorPoint property, but they lack a center property. So, what you want to do is calculate the center manually by doing calculations on the position property, anchorPoint property and the translation of your layer.

I can't provide any code, since I am not sure which method you are using, but to wrap it up, you have to roll out your own center calculator either ways.

---

Please look at the pictures below carefully (courtesy of Stanford iPhone Development course slides):

**Before applying any rotation:**

[image]

**After applying a 45° rotation:**

[image]

**Conclusion:**

Notice how the old center was (300, 225) and the new center is, well not new! It's the same. If you are doing everything correctly, your center should be the same. If you have another point within the view that you'd like to calculate, then you'd have to that yourself.

Please also notice how the frame changed from (200, 100, 200, 250) to (140, 65, 320, 320). This is just how UIKit does it's magic.

Comment: However if the transformation is a translation or a scale with a different anchorPoint, then the center of the view will be different (on the screen).

Comment: @Jonathan. yeah, and it should be calculated properly same as the illustrations above. If you have different results, please tell me

Comment: @Jonathan. BTW, are you using `CALayer`s? I am not familiar with `UIView`s having anchor points.

Comment: oh right sorry I misunderstood I thought you meant the value of the center is not meant to change, as you're answer says the center is "not new", however in same cases it will be new. And if you change the anchorPoint of the view's layer then it will affect the transform you apply. (as the transform and center of UIView just wrap methods on the view's layer)

Comment: @Jonathan. Oh well, I guess it's just up to you then to roll out your own code and calculate stuff as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Yeah in my head I thought that center should in theory be the same but I also swore I read somewhere that as soon as we apply transforms we can't use the normal frame rect for anything (as if it becomes undefined).  I have been applying translations so I've manually calculated the center as you've suggested and it's working great now, cheers :)